# Gridding and reprojection of raster shifting its placement

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, gdal

I've been using Python to get through my workflow of:

1. Convert input file to a shapefile
2. Use the shapefile to calculate extents, cell size, etc
3. Grid the raster using `gdal_grid`
4. Re-project the raster to EPSG:3857

This all runs great - no issues.
However, once reprojected, the raster seems to shift position which is confusing me. When I run the same commands on the command line then my resulting reprojected tif is in the correct place (Number 1 on pic). Whereas after running the python code it is shifted (Number 2 on pic).

I can't seem to pinpoint where its happening or why... can anyone advise?

[image]